# How to do a search query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know how to do an `IF` statement inside a `WHERE` statement depending on the value of `@FirstName` and `@LastName` (if it's `null`
Here is my code:

```
SELECT tblCustomers.CustomerFirstName, tblCustomers.CustomerLastName FROm tblCustomers
    where CustomerFirstName = @FirstName and CustomerLastName = @LastName
```

Comment: What needs to happen if value of either variable is null?

Comment: If the parameter is null, should it return everything?

Comment: Be more specific with your condition

Comment: I have answers but i am leaving it open for other people to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT tblCustomers.CustomerFirstName, tblCustomers.CustomerLastName 
FROM tblCustomers
WHERE CustomerFirstName = COALESCE(@FirstName, CustomerFirstName)
AND CustomerLastName = COALESCE(@LastName, CustomerLastName)
```

This way, if a parameter is null the where clause will ignore it.
Please note that it will not return any rows where the columns are null.

If your columns are nullable and you want to renurn the rows where they are null, you will need to use the where clause suggested in Bennjoe Mordeno's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use CASE Statement in WHERE Clause :

SELECT tblCustomers.CustomerFirstName, tblCustomers.CustomerLastName 
FROM tblCustomers
WHERE CustomerFirstName = CASE 
      WHEN ISNULL(@FirstName,'') <> '' THEN @FirstName ELSE CustomerFirstName END AND CustomerLastName = WHEN ISNULL(@LastName,'') <> '' THEN @LastName ELSE CustomerLastName END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tblCustomers.CustomerFirstName, tblCustomers.CustomerLastName FROm tblCustomers
where (CustomerFirstName = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL) and (CustomerLastName = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL)
```

If the parameter is null, it doesnt have to match the column